# How to move all pdf files in to another directory

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to move all pdf files in C:\ to H:\

```
I googled and was not able to find a sufficient answer. Only if you know the exact file name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        For Each x In New DirectoryInfo("C:\").GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)' or AllDirectories
            File.Copy(x.FullName, Path.Combine("H:\", x.Name), False) 'Overwrite = FALSE
        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each x In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly) ' Or SearchAllSubDirectories
        If x.EndsWith(".pdf") Then IO.File.Copy(x, "H:\", False) 'Overwrite = FALSE
    Next
```